# Looking for fast caching DNS resolver (server or library)

Tags: dns

I need to get reverse DNS for a large number of IPs on daily bases. Some of the IPs will come many times over each day. I want to catch the rDNS value for 24 hours, including 'no record' responses.

I am looking for software (or library) that would allow me to:

- Ignore authoritative TTL
- Cache 'no record' responses (for the TTL I specify).

Yes, we can write such library on our own, but it is hard for me to imagine no one done it yet. Yet... cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among others, `unbound` could do it.

See in its manual (https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/) the following:

```
   cache-max-ttl: <seconds>
          Time to live maximum for  RRsets  and  messages  in  the  cache.
          Default  is  86400  seconds  (1  day).  If the maximum kicks in,
          responses to clients still get decrementing TTLs  based  on  the
          original  (larger)  values.   When the internal TTL expires, the
          cache item has expired.  Can be set lower to force the  resolver
          to query for data often, and not trust (very large) TTL values.

   cache-min-ttl: <seconds>
          Time  to  live  minimum  for  RRsets  and messages in the cache.
          Default is 0.  If the minimum kicks in, the data is  cached  for
          longer than the domain owner intended, and thus less queries are
          made to look up the data.  Zero makes sure the data in the cache
          is  as the domain owner intended, higher values, especially more
          than an hour or so, can lead to trouble as the data in the cache
          does not match up with the actual data any more.

   cache-max-negative-ttl: <seconds>
          Time to live maximum for negative responses, these have a SOA in
          the authority section that is limited in time.  Default is 3600.
          This applies to nxdomain and nodata answers.
```

PS: your question would be most ontopic on SoftwareRecommandations than here as it is not really a programming problem (or at least until you decide to program such a software yourself)